# Constant connection between C# Winform and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, connection

Is it possible to create a connection that remains open as long as the WinForm application is open?
At the moment I declare a public connection string in the class of the form and then I initiate a new connection in each private void. I am hoping there is a way I could open and close the connection only once after loading and before closing the application?

Comment: Declare a private System.Data.SQLClient.SqlConnection object as part of your Form, instantiate it and open it in the form load event, close the connection in the closing of the form. I think this is bad design though, as what happens if your project crashes before closing the database connection.

Comment: Why? This is very bad idea. You want to close and dispose of your connections immediately when you are done using it. If you leave connections open you are going to decimate your connection pool.

Comment: That sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: Close the connection after your query. The connection pool in the .net framework handle the connections and reuse it if it needed, check this [sql-server-connection-pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling)

Comment: I was hoping I would not have to open and close the connection each time but apparently this should be done. Is it possible to call a function that would open and close the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do this easily. Simply create a `SqlConnection` variable in your form and initialize it in your `Load` event. Be sure to close it when your form unloads.

However, most databases can have multiple clients. And if they start keeping the database open like this, you can begin to have horrible performance in the best case. In the worst case, other requests will be completely blocked while your program is running. If there are multiple instances of your application, then that would obviously be a major problem.

For these reasons, virtually no one is doing what you are asking to do. And I would strongly suggest you make sure you understand all the issues before doing it.